# Removing any element with a certain value from XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Using a transform I've found here on Stack Overflow, I'm able to remove empty tags from my XML using XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
    "*[not(@*|*|comment()|processing-instruction())
     and normalize-space()=''
     ]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My question is:  **How would I go about removing *any* elements with a particular value?** e.g. my XML also has default blank values like :

```
          <BIRTHDATE>0000-00-00</BIRTHDATE>
          <DEATHDATE>0000-00-00</DEATHDATE>
```

I've seen examples that remove one particular element with a certain value, but how can I match *any* element with a certain value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part that indicates empty value is `and normalize-space()=''`, you can modify that part to match empty or particular value like so :

```
<xsl:template match=
    "*[not(@*|*|comment()|processing-instruction())
     and (normalize-space()='' or normalize-space()='PARTICULAR_VALUE_HERE')
     ]"/>
```

Comment: I suspect there are residual criteria from an earlier answer that OP may not want here.  For example, `<BIRTHDATE attr="1">0000-00-00</BIRTHDATE>` will not be removed, among other exclusions that are not mentioned in this question.  To remove precisely "***any** elements with a particular value*", see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31095707/290085) for a simple solution.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use the identify transformation plus a null override for elements whose string value matches the string you wish to remove ("0000-00-00"):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*[ not(*) and . = '0000-00-00']"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this works too. 

Out of curiosity - is there a way to match all flavours of 0, rather than using a string comparison? 

Let's say I have elements with various default '0' values, one has 0, one has 0.0, one has 0000... can I match them all with one expression?

Comment: With XSLT 2.0 you can write `match="*[. = ('0', '0.0', '0000')]"`, with XSLT 1.0 you can write `or` expressions `match="*[. = '0' or . = '0.0' or . = '0000']"`.